# Weighing balls of three colors

Tags: weighing

You have six balls. Two are red, two are white, and two are blue. One ball of each color weighs 6kg. The other three all weigh 6.01 kg.

> How many uses of a two pan balance does it take to determine the weights of all the balls?

Source:  *Mathematical Circus*, Martin Gardner, p. 127.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need

> two weighings.

First,

> weigh R1+W1 against R2+B2.

Now

> if they balance, then we have either R:1 W:2 B:2 (meaning red ball 1 is the heavy one, etc.) or R:2 W:1 B:1. Weighing pretty much anything against anything else will distinguish these two.

On the other hand,

> if one side is heavier, WLOG it's R1+W1 > R2+B2. Then we necessarily have R:1, and the others can't be W:2 B:2. So we have one of W:1 B:1, W:1 B:2, W:2 B:1. Now weigh W1 against B1. In those three cases we have respectively W1 = B1, W1 > B1, W1 < B1.

Now

> no third weighing is necessary and this paragraph is just here so it isn't too obvious from the structure of my answer what the desired number is

and

> I suppose I should say explicitly that if the first weighing yields R1+W1 < R2+B2 instead, we just need to swap "white" and "blue" and "light" and "heavy" in the second-weighing strategy above

and therefore

> we are done, in all cases, after at most two weighings.

I believe

> the first weighing here is essentially the only possibility that makes two weighings enough.

Answer (score 1):

Just a very slight variation to Gareth's correct answer and how I arrived at essentially the same answer

> if you end up with R1+W1 > R2+B2, weigh R1+R2 against W1+B2. Because we know W1 is either greater or equal to B2: if R1+R2 > W1+B2 both W1 and B2 are light, if R1+R2 < W1+B2 then both are heavy and if R1+R2 = W1+B2 then W1 is heavy and B2 is light.